# Search box missing from header when navigating from team site to communication site

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, cache, search-box, communication-site

We are building a Sharepoint Online site for a client, and they use a communication site for their start page. On that page the search box is up in the header. They also use team sites, and on those pages the search box is over the left navigation.

We noticed that when navigating from a team site to the start page the search box never shows up. We suspect this is due to some sort of caching of the header? When inspecting the html we see that the search box isn't in the DOM tree at all, but on reloading the page it shows up.

Does anyone else have this problem, and have you been able to solve it?

EDIT: It's not just the search box thats missing, also a class on the canvas is missing making the whole design left aligned instead of center aligned.